# Why are my HTML buttons in Visual Studio not creating Event Handlers when double clicked?

Tags: c#, html, css, .net, visual-studio-2015

I have added buttons into a web form in Visual Studio 2015 using HTML. So those buttons are in the design tab. When i double click the button in the Design Tab. It is not opening the ASPX.CS page. Is that normal? I was under the impression that i would work like that. Instead i have to go and manually code each event handler.

I have searched google and tried to run repairs on Visual Studio but found no avail.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Module2LabExercise.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>  
    <head>    
    <title> 
        Currency Converter
    </title>  
</head>  
<body>    
    <form runat = "server">      
        <div>        
            Convert: &nbsp;        
            <input type = "text" ID = "US" runat = "server" />        
            &nbsp; U.S. dollars to &nbsp;        
            <select ID = "Currency" runat = "server" />        
            <br /> <br />       
            <input type = "submit" value = "OK" ID = "Convert" 
OnServerClick = "Convert_ServerClick" runat = "server" />  
            <input type = "submit" value = "Show Graph" ID = "ShowGraph" 
OnServerClick = "ShowGraph_ServerClick" runat = "server" />      
            <br /> <br />          
            <img id="Graph" runat="server" src="//:0"/>
            <br /> <br />        
            <p style = "font-weight: bold" ID = "Result" runat = "server" 
>
            </p>  
        </div>    
   </form>  
    </body> 
</html>
```

`

I was thinking that if i double click the button. It would auto open the Event Handler and create the event handler. If i am wrong. Please correct me and let me know. Just coming here because im out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

you add that code in your backend of button implementation:
here is code

```
Response.redirect("ex.aspx");
```

ex.aspx is your file name

if it not working then add:

```
Server.Transfer("ex.aspx");
```

Comment: I tried adding that and got nothing. Where in my code does it go?

Comment: you must use onClick instead of OnServerclick it will work and give file name that location

Comment: file extention is wrong you only use "WebForm1.aspx" and use it on inverted commas.

Answer (score 0):

VS won't do this for non-ASP tags, but if you instead put:

```
<asp:Button ID="Convert"  runat="server" />
```

instead of

```
<input type = "submit" ID = "Convert" runat = "server" />
```

Then you'll get that feature

Answer (score 0):

As for

> It is not opening the ASPX.CS page. Is that normal?

yes it is normal as the button is an `HTML` `input[type="submit"]` with `runat="server` and not an `asp.net` wrapped button like: `<asp:button>`. Hence it is not transpiled by the `Asp.net`.

And why are you using `runat="server"` on an HTML button? If you really want a server-side event to be called use the `<asp:Button>` that way you will be able to create the `click-event` on double-clicking the button.

But if you still persist on using it you have to 3 ways attach the `click` event-handler to the `HTML` button.

> Event handler in **aspx** designer page.

```
//attach a script tag to your aspx page and add the click event to it.

<script language="C#" runat="server"> 
    protected void Convert_ServerClick_manual1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //your code here
    }
</script>
```

Now just add an `onserverclick="Convert_ServerClick_manual1"` attrubute to the button.

> Attach an event handler on the `pageload` event of `aspx.cs` page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Convert.Click += Convert_ServerClick_manual2;
}
```

now define the event handler below the `pageload` event:

```
private void Convert_ServerClick_manual2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //your code here
}
```

> Manual event handler

```
//just create the event handler for your button on the `aspx.cs` page and paste the handler name to the `HTML` button.

private void Convert_ServerClick_Manual3(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //your code here
}
```

Then in your design page use:

```
<input type = "submit" value = "OK" ID = "Convert" OnServerClick = "Convert_ServerClick_manual3" runat = "server" />
```

manually create an `event handler` for the input `button[runat="server"]` in the `<yourPage>aspx.cs` and attach it to the `HTML` button.

Comment: Okay. That makes sense. That is what i have been doing. I am honestly not sure why we are using HTML buttons. This is a college course and i am just following what the book says. It just made it seem like i could double click the button and open the event handler page. Thank you for the clarification.